# Devstack, Metadata service - How to preset configuration

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

**It's the background of my question:** I'm running a Devstack(stable Juno release) on a Ubuntu 14.10 machine with Neutron enabled. When I spawn a VM, ssh to it and try to curl the metadata service(`curl http://169.254.169.254`), it returns a 500 error. The problem here is, that the configurations in `/etc/neutron/metadata_agent.ini` are set wrong. They look like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
...
auth_url = http://<my_ip_adress>:35357
...
admin_tenant_name = %SERVICE_TENANT_NAME%
admin_user = %SERVICE_USER%
admin_password = %SERVICE_PASSWORD%
```

After I have changed them to

```
[DEFAULT]
...
auth_url = http://<my_ip_adress>:35357/v2.0
...
admin_tenant_name = admin
admin_user = admin
admin_password = <admin_pwd>
```

everything works fine.

**My question is now:** how can I define these settings in my `local.conf` so I don't have to do it manually every time I unstack/stack the Devstack installation? Or is it a bug in the Devstack installation script?

Answer (score 0):

You can change configurations in `/etc/neutron/metadata_agent.ini` by setting in `local.conf`:

```
[[post-config|$Q_META_CONF_FILE]]
[DEFAULT]
...
auth_url = http://<my_ip_adress>:35357/v2.0
...
admin_tenant_name = admin
admin_user = admin
admin_password = <admin_pwd>
```